# Flutter How to show container expand and collapse element's?

Tags: flutter, containers

I would like to shows a container elements with expansion and collapse effect.
[image]

It is not combined with `AppBar`.

Here is my  `container` code:

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (_height == 200) {
          setState(() {
            _height = 100.0;
          });
        } else {
          _updateState();
        }
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 550),
        height: _height,
        width: Get.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
              spreadRadius: 2,
              blurRadius: 10,
              offset: const Offset(0, 3),
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
           Text("0.0"),
           Text("0.0"),
           //Widget1(),
           //Widget2(),
           //Widget3(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I want it to show my other `Widgets` when I click it.

Also I tried `ExpansionPanelList` and `ExpansionTile` but they are not working like what I  exactly want. Also I don't want to use  `SliverAppBar` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example might help you:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _height = 100;

  void onClick() {
    if (_height == 300) {
      setState(() {
        _height = 100.0;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _height = 300;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> _widgets = [
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
              spreadRadius: 2,
              blurRadius: 10,
              offset: const Offset(0, 3),
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 100,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              onClick();
            },
            child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 550),
              height: _height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                    spreadRadius: 2,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                ),
              ),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                child: Column(
                  children: _widgets,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

result:

[image: result]

Comment: After a few recode it worked. I accepting your answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can add condition in you column like this

```
children: [
           Text("0.0"),
           Text("0.0"),
           if(_height == 200)
           Widget1(),
           if(_height == 200)
           Widget2(),
           if(_height == 200)
           Widget3(),
          ],
```

also you can use AnimatedSwitcher
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html

Comment: It returns overflowed error if child is too big for parent's height. Still thank you.